# rvest trouble: POST submission

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying download data from a USGS post form using rvest. What am I doing wrong?

```
make_url = function(base_url, parameter_list)
  parameter_list %>%
  names %>%
  paste(parameter_list, sep = "=", collapse = "&") %>%
  paste(base_url, ., sep = "")

session = 
  list(sn = "01170000") %>%
  make_url("http://ida.water.usgs.gov/ida/available_records.cfm?", .) %>%
  html_session

test = 
  session %>%
  html_form %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  set_values(fromdate = "1990-10-01") %>%
  set_values(todate = "2007-09-30") %>%
  set_values(rtype = "3") %>%
  submit_form(session, .)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for either `rvest` or a session. The following function will take in station and dates and returns a data frame with the data file comment that the USGS spits out with each download.

It uses the "download compressed file" option to save bandwidth and speed up the download. It makes temporary files to read the data but cleans up after itself. Columns are converted to proper type (you can omit that part of the code if you want to, though). You can omit the comment attaching as well if you don't need it (it seemed to have useful information to me).

`readr::read_lines()` is used for speed and you can use `readLines()` instead if you don't want to rely on the `readr` package.

The conversion to a `tibble` version of a `data.frame` is mainly for better printing but it has other potential advantages, so you can omit that as well if you don't want to rely on the `tibble` package.

There's a hard-coded  99 second timeout but you can parameterize it if desired.

```
library(httr)
library(readr)
library(tibble)

#' Retrieve IDA Station Data
#'
#' @param site_no site id
#' @param date_from records from date YYYY-mm-dd
#' @param date_to records to date YYYY-mm-dd
#' @return a parsed, type-converted data frame with a comments attribute. 
#' @example
#' deerfield <- get_ida("01170000", "1990-10-01", "2007-09-30")
#'
#' head(deerfield)
#'
#' cat(comment(deerfield))

get_ida <- function(site_no, date_from, date_to) {

  date_from_time <- sprintf("%s 00:15:00.0", date_from)
  date_to_time <- sprintf("%s 23:45:00.0", date_to)

  ida_referer <- sprintf("http://ida.water.usgs.gov/ida/available_records.cfm?sn=%s", site_no)

  tf <- tempfile(".zip")

  res <- POST(url = "http://ida.water.usgs.gov/ida/available_records_process.cfm",
              body = list(fromdate = date_from,
                          todate = date_to,
                          mindatetime = date_from_time,
                          maxdatetime = date_to_time,
                          site_no = site_no,
                          rtype = "2",
                          submit1 = "Retrieve+Data"),
              add_headers(Origin="http://ida.water.usgs.gov",
                          Referer=ida_referer),
              write_disk(tf),
              timeout(99),
              encode = "form")

  fils <- unzip(tf, exdir=tempdir())
  tmp <- read_lines(fils)

  unlink(tf)
  unlink(fils)

  comments <- grep("^#", tmp, value=TRUE)
  records <- grep("^#", tmp, value=TRUE, invert=TRUE)
  header <- records[1:2]
  records <- records[-(1:2)]
  cols <- strsplit(header[1], "[[:space:]]+")[[1]]

  comments <- paste0(comments, collapse="\n")
  records <- paste0(records, collapse="\n")

  df <- read_tsv(records, col_names=cols, "cccnnnnc")
  df$date_time <- as.POSIXct(df$date_time, format="%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
  df <- as_tibble(df)

  comment(df) <- comments

  df

}
```

Proof it works:

```
deerfield <- get_ida("01170000", "1990-10-01", "2007-09-30")

dplyr::glimpse(deerfield)
## Observations: 550,917
## Variables: 8
## $ site_no     <chr> "01170000", "01170000", "01170000", "01170000", "0117000...
## $ date_time   <time> 1990-10-01 00:15:00, 1990-10-01 00:30:00, 1990-10-01 00...
## $ tz_cd       <chr> "EDT", "EDT", "EDT", "EDT", "EDT", "EDT", "EDT", "EDT", ...
## $ dd          <dbl> 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,...
## $ accuracy_cd <dbl> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,...
## $ value       <dbl> 146, 139, 135, 143, 154, 166, 171, 175, 171, 166, 162, 1...
## $ prec        <dbl> 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,...
## $ remark      <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...

head(deerfield)
## # A tibble: 6 x 8
##    site_no           date_time tz_cd    dd accuracy_cd value  prec remark
##      <chr>              <time> <chr> <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <chr>
## 1 01170000 1990-10-01 00:15:00   EDT     7           1   146     3   <NA>
## 2 01170000 1990-10-01 00:30:00   EDT     7           1   139     3   <NA>
## 3 01170000 1990-10-01 00:45:00   EDT     7           1   135     3   <NA>
## 4 01170000 1990-10-01 01:00:00   EDT     7           1   143     3   <NA>
## 5 01170000 1990-10-01 01:15:00   EDT     7           1   154     3   <NA>
## 6 01170000 1990-10-01 01:30:00   EDT     7           1   166     3   <NA>

cat(comment(deerfield))
# retrieved: 2016-09-12 05:32:34 CST
#
# Data for the following station is contained in this file
# ---------------------------------------------------------
#  USGS 01170000 DEERFIELD RIVER NEAR WEST DEERFIELD, MA
#
# This data file was retrieved from the USGS
# instantaneous data archive at
# http://ida.water.usgs.gov
#
# ---------------------WARNING---------------------
# The instantaneous data you have obtained from
# this automated U.S. Geological Survey database
# may or may not have been the basis for the published
# daily mean discharges for this station. Although
# automated filtering has been used to compare these
# data to the published daily mean values and to remove
# obviously bad data, there may still be significant
# error in individual values. Users are strongly
# encouraged to review all data carefully prior to use.
# These data are released on the condition that neither
# the USGS nor the United States Government may be held
# liable for any damages resulting from its use.
#
# This file consists of tab-separated columns of the
# following fields.
#
# column       column definition
# -----------  -----------------------------------------
# site_no      USGS site identification number
# date_time     date and time in format (YYYYMMDDhhmmss)
# tz_cd        time zone
# dd           internal USGS sensor designation (''data descriptor'')
# accuracy_cd  accuracy code
#                   0 - A daily mean discharge calculated from the instantaneous
#                       data on this day is 0.01 cubic feet per second
#                       or less and the published daily mean is zero.
#                   1 - A daily mean discharge calculated from the instantaneous
#                       data on this day matches the published daily mean
#                       within 1 percent.
#                   2 - A daily mean discharge calculated from the instantaneous
#                       data on this day matches the published daily mean
#                       from greater than 1 to 5 percent.
#                   3 - A daily mean discharge calculated from the instantaneous
#                       values on this day matches the published daily mean
#                       from greater than 5 to 10 percent.
#                   9 - The instantaneous value is considered correct by the
#                       collecting USGS Water Science Center. A published daily
#                       mean value does not exist and/or no comparison was made.
# value        discharge in cubic feet per second
# precision    digits of precision in the discharge
# remark       optional remark code
#                 Remark  Explanation
#                   <     Actual value is known to be less than reported value.
#                   >     Actual value is known to be greater than reported value.
#                   &     Value is affected by unspecified reasons.
#                   A     Value is affected by ice at the measurement site.
#                   B     Value is affected by backwater at the measurement site.
#                   e     Value has been estimated by USGS personnel.
#                   E     Value was computed from an estimated value.
#                   F     Value was modified due to automated filtering.
#                   K     Value is affected by instrument calibration drift.
#                   R     Rating is undefined for this value.
#
#
```

Comment: Great answer! Really above and beyond. This seems like it might be nice in as part of a package? I'd still like to see if there's a way to get rvest working. The hadleyverse syntax is so nice.

Comment: Well, `httr` _technically_ is part of the hadleyverse ;-) I thought about the same thing w/r/t a potential pkg, but the IDA site says all data is eventually moving to the NWIS site and there's already an R pkg to access that data - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/waterData/waterData.pdf - but if they keep the archive standalone it def would be something I'd think about doing.

Comment: It's worth noting that this data has been separate from the main USGS site for at least two years.

Comment: Aye, but they even say on the IDA main page that the data is being migrated.

Comment: Ok, I figured out how to fix rvest, the key is just to add the add_headers argument as a ... to submit_request so it eventually gets passed to POST. I have two questions: how did you figure out that was the right thing to do, and is this something rvest could do automatically?

Comment: I think Referer is the only necessary header, and Referer is just session$url

Comment: I wrote a package called `curlconverter` which takes the "Copy as cURL" value from inspecting a browser session with Developer Tools and builds both a request data structure and full `httr` function. I usually strip away the cruft from the resultant function until I get a minimal working `httr` call.

Comment: I've added my code using rvest below for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's a way to get rvest to work:

```
library(magrittr)

make_url = function(base_url, parameter_list = list(), ...) {
  together_list = 
    parameter_list %>%
    c(list(...) )

  together_list %>%
    names %>%
    paste(together_list, sep = "=", collapse = "&") %>%
    paste(base_url, ., sep = "?")
}

download_ida = function(site_no, 
                        fromdate = "1990-10-01", 
                        todate = "2007-09-30", 
                        dir = ".",
                        filename = paste(site_no, "txt", sep = ".") ) {

  session = 
    "http://ida.water.usgs.gov/ida/available_records.cfm" %>%
    make_url(sn = "01170000") %>%
    html_session

  form = 
    session %>%
    html_form %>%
    .[[1]] %>%
    set_values(fromdate = fromdate,
               todate = todate,
               rtype = "2")

  tempfile = tempfile(".zip")

  submit_form(session, form, submit = NULL,
              httr::write_disk(tempfile,
                               overwrite = TRUE),
              httr::add_headers(Referer = session$url) )

  filename = file.path(dir, filename)

  tempfile %>%
    unzip(exdir = dir) %>%
    file.rename(filename)

  filename
}

read_ida = function(filename) {

  col_names = 
    filename %>%
    readr::read_tsv(comment = "#", n_max = 1, col_names = FALSE)

  filename %>%
    readr::read_tsv(comment = "#", skip= 2, col_names = FALSE, na = "Ice",
                    col_types = cols(X2 = col_datetime(format = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))) %>%
    stats::setNames(col_names)
}

deerfield = 
  "01170000" %>%
  download_ida %>%
  read_ida
```

But there's a caveat: rvest currently has an open pull request, https://github.com/hadley/rvest/pull/161 , which is needed to get this to work. To that end, it is necessary to redefine both submit_request and submit_form integrating the new pull request:

```
submit_request = function(form, submit = NULL) {
  is_submit <- function(x)
    if ( is.null(x$type) ) FALSE else
      tolower(x$type) %in% c("submit", "image", "button")

  submits <- Filter(is_submit, form$fields)

  if (length(submits) == 0) {
    stop("Could not find possible submission target.", call. = FALSE)
  }
  if (is.null(submit)) {
    submit <- names(submits)[[1]]
    message("Submitting with '", submit, "'")
  }
  if (!(submit %in% names(submits))) {
    stop("Unknown submission name '", submit, "'.\n", "Possible values: ", 
         paste0(names(submits), collapse = ", "), call. = FALSE)
  }
  other_submits <- setdiff(names(submits), submit)
  method <- form$method
  if (!(method %in% c("POST", "GET"))) {
    warning("Invalid method (", method, "), defaulting to GET", 
            call. = FALSE)
    method <- "GET"
  }
  url <- form$url
  fields <- form$fields
  fields <- Filter(function(x) length(x$value) > 0, fields)
  fields <- fields[setdiff(names(fields), other_submits)]
  values <- pluck(fields, "value")
  names(values) <- names(fields)
  list(method = method, encode = form$enctype, url = url, values = values)
}

submit_form = function(session, form, submit = NULL, ...) {
  request <- submit_request(form, submit)
  url <- xml2::url_absolute(form$url, session$url)
  if (request$method == "GET") {
    rvest:::request_GET(session, url = url, query = request$values, ...)
  } else if (request$method == "POST") {
    rvest:::request_POST(session, url = url, body = request$values, 
                         encode = request$encode, ...)
  } else {
    stop("Unknown method: ", request$method, call. = FALSE)
  }
}
```

Hopefully the pull request will get merged soon.